# Sling job not being processed with custom serializable property

Tags: aem, sling

I have created custom Serializable class, and I add it into payload of necessary Sling Job

```
public SomeClass extends Serializable {
    //Implementaton details
}

.......
//some service

Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<>();
payload.put("property1", someClassObject);

jobManager.createJob("some/job/topic").properties(payload).add();
```

As a reusult job is successfully created and assigned, but `process` method of `JobConsumer` is not triggered.

[image: crx /var/eventing]

I have enabled TRACE log level on org.apache.sling.event.jobs, logs say the same: job is added and assigned, nothing else is happened:

```
20.03.2019 11:15:00.263 DEBUG [sling-threadpool-15f9e0b4-a24d-4b0d-bf4a-433ec604e41d-(apache-sling-job-thread-pool)-27-<main queue>(com/some/Service)] org.apache.sling.event.jobs.audit ASSIGN OK bb92b672-1b0d-4fe8-bf5e-9194a934f249 : 2019/3/20/11/15/bb92b672-1b0d-4fe8-bf5e-9194a934f249_50
20.03.2019 11:15:00.263 DEBUG [sling-threadpool-15f9e0b4-a24d-4b0d-bf4a-433ec604e41d-(apache-sling-job-thread-pool)-27-<main queue>(com/some/Service)] org.apache.sling.event.jobs.audit ADD OK topic=some/job/topic, properties={spreadsheet=com.some.project.SomeClass@7acdf4a2} : 2019/3/20/11/15/bb92b672-1b0d-4fe8-bf5e-9194a934f249_50
```

If I pass standard serializable objects like String, Integer and etc; Job is started, and I could find evidence in logs:

```
20.03.2019 11:15:00.012 DEBUG [sling-threadpool-15f9e0b4-a24d-4b0d-bf4a-433ec604e41d-(apache-sling-job-thread-pool)-27-<main queue>(com/some/Service)] org.apache.sling.event.jobs.audit START OK : 2019/3/20/11/15/bb92b672-1b0d-4fe8-bf5e-9194a934f249_49
```

How could I resolve problem of Sling Job processing?

Tested on AEM 6.4.2 and 6.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your custom class is prohibited from being deserialized. Actually all classes are prohibited from being deserialized as described [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/deserialization-not-allowed-error.html) . You should whitelist classes that you would like to be deserializable.

Specific **RuntimeException** is only seen when you create debug logger on **org.apache.sling.event.impl** instead of **org.apache.sling.event.jobs** :

```
*DEBUG* [sling-default-137-Registered Service.4303] org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.queues.QueueJobCache Unable to read resource.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Deserialization not allowed for class TestEnum
    at org.kantega.notsoserial.DefaultNotSoSerial.preventDeserialization(DefaultNotSoSerial.java:256)
    at org.kantega.notsoserial.DefaultNotSoSerial.onBeforeResolveClass(DefaultNotSoSerial.java:248)
    at org.kantega.notsoserial.ObjectInputStreamClassVisitor.onBeforeResolveClass(ObjectInputStreamClassVisitor.java:48)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1868)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnum(ObjectInputStream.java:1994)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1570)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.JcrPropertyMapCacheEntry.convertToType(JcrPropertyMapCacheEntry.java:330) [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.JcrPropertyMapCacheEntry.convertToType(JcrPropertyMapCacheEntry.java:231) [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrValueMap.get(JcrValueMap.java:105) [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.8]
    at org.apache.sling.event.impl.support.ResourceHelper.cloneValueMap(ResourceHelper.java:203) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.10]
  at org.apache.sling.event.impl.jobs.Utility.readJob(Utility.java:181) [org.apache.sling.event:4.2.10]
```

[Here](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-event/blob/691a8b8352ae27e5d5c346f891bec8313522b355/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/event/impl/jobs/Utility.java#L221) is the line of code that is catching this exception.